# Multer and ImageMagick with Express.js: upload, resize, reorient

Tags: node.js, image, express, imagemagick, multer

I have an Express application that gets an image from a user via a form. There are several things I need to do with the image, and as it gets more complex, I'm not sure how to handle it. It is a message board post where there are some required text fields and an optional image upload. I need to:

1. Find the orientation of the image from EXIF data and reorient it if needed
2. Save a copy of the original image to the server (done)
3. Create a thumbnail of the image and save it to the server (done)
4. Save the record to the database, whether or not there's an uploaded image (done)

I'm concerned about the order in which I'm doing things, wondering if there's a more efficient way. I know I can call `upload` inside the route instead of passing it in, but I'd like to not repeat myself when I save the record to the database, since I need to save it whether there's an image or not.

I have code that's working for the final 3 steps, but am open to suggestions on how to improve it. For the first step, I'm stumped at how to go about getting the orientation of the original and rotating it if needed. Is this something I need to do client-side instead? And how do I work it into the existing code?

Here's the code:

Setup

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var fileExt = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    if (fileExt == 'jpeg'){ fileExt = 'jpg';}
    cb(null, req.user.username + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + fileExt);
  }
})

var restrictImgType = function(req, file, cb) {

    var allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png'];
      if (allowedTypes.indexOf(req.file.mimetype) !== -1){
        // To accept the file pass `true`
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        // To reject this file pass `false`
        cb(null, false);
       //cb(new Error('File type not allowed'));// How to pass an error?
      }
};

var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: {fileSize:3000000, fileFilter:restrictImgType} });
```

In Route

```
router.post('/new',upload.single('photo'),function(req,res){
    var photo = null;
    var allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png'];
    if (req.file){
            photo = '/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
            // save thumbnail -- should this part go elsewhere?
            im.crop({
              srcPath: './public/uploads/'+ req.file.filename,
              dstPath: './public/uploads/thumbs/100x100/'+ req.file.filename,
              width: 100,
              height: 100
            }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log('100x100 thumbnail created');
            });

            // I can get orientation here, 
            // but the image has already been saved
            im.readMetadata('./public/uploads/'+ req.file.filename, function(err, metadata){
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log("exif orientation: " + metadata.exif.orientation);
            });

    }

    // Save it
    new Post({
        username: req.user.username,
        title: req.body.title,
        body: req.body.messagebody,
        photo: photo 
    }).save(function(err){
        if (err){ console.log(err); }
        res.redirect('/messageboard');
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help